# Kendo-Vue Excel Export Currency Formatting

Tags: export-to-excel, xlsx, currency-formatting, kendo-ui-vue

I'm trying to format the excel cells using cellOptions for currency, and haven't been able to find something that formats currency universally for other countries. In my grid definitions, I have:

{ field: 'monetaryValue', title: 'Monetary Value', width: '200', format: '{0:c2}', filter: 'text', hidden: true, cellOptions: { format: '$#,##0.00'} },

This will format 888.8 to $888.80, which is great for USD, however won't be for other countries. the {0:c2} kendo accepts for formatting any currency to the grid pending on locale, but I haven't been able to find documentation for excel having a universal currency formatter.

I tried seeing if excel would accept cellOptions: { format: '{0:c2}'}, or '{0:c}', '{0:currency}', '{currency}'. None of those formatted like I'd hoped. the USD is working for now, I'm assuming I'll have to do an if-conditional to check the locale and render the desired format, but I'm hoping someone may know of an excel accepted format that is more universal.